Rcar H3 salvator X evaluation board
in RCar h3 board (salvator X), does it have inbuilt GSM or Wifi module?
would like to know whether GSM or Wifi modulesa are present in RCar h3 salvator X board.if not how can i implement a Wi-Fi module.what are the requirements?
